# Adding and removing extensionattribute to AD object

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm using powershell to modify some AD extensionattribute.

This is my code to add an extensionattribute

```
Set-ADUser -Identity "anyUser" -Add @{extensionAttribute4="myString"}
```

It works, but how can I remove the same extensionattribute? I can't find anything similar to `-remove`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try using the `-Clear` parameter

Example:`-Clear Attribute1LDAPDisplayName, Attribute2LDAPDisplayName`

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617215.aspx

Answer (score 14):

I used the following today - It works!

Add a value to an extensionAttribute

```
 $ThisUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties extensionAttribute1
    Set-ADUser –Identity $ThisUser -add @{"extensionattribute1"="MyString"}
```

Remove a value from an extensionAttribute

```
  $ThisUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties extensionAttribute1
  Set-ADUser –Identity $ThisUser -Clear "extensionattribute1"
```

Answer (score 3):

I have struggled a long time to modify the extension attributes in our domain.
Then I wrote a powershell script and created an editor with a GUI to set and remove extAttributes from an account.

If you like, you can take a look at it at http://toolbocks.de/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4

I'm sorry, that the description in the text is in German. The GUI itself is in English.

I use this script on a regular basis in our domain and it never deleted anything or did any other harm. I provide no guarantee, that this script works as expected in your domain. But as I provide the source, you can (and should) have a look at it, before you run it.

Comment: the URL is not working ? would you be able to share it again please?

Answer (score 1):

Extension attributes are added by Exchange. According to [this Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee423541%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) something like this should work:

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity "anyUser" -ExtensionCustomAttribute4 @{Remove="myString"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set-ADUser -Identity anyUser -Replace @{extensionAttribute4="myString"}
```

This is also usefull

Comment: Will this work if the current value is not set, or will it fail unless there is already a value in there?

Comment: Yes it will work regardless, either replacing an existing value, or adding one if there isn't one there already.

Answer (score 0):

Or the -Remove parameter

```
Set-ADUser -Identity anyUser -Remove @{extensionAttribute4="myString"}
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear the value you can always reset it to $Null.  For example:

`Set-Mailbox -Identity "username" -CustomAttribute1 $Null`