# How I can read all user in a OU and change the Attributes with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap, active-directory-group

Hi I have a question to powershell and active directory. I want to change a attribute by all users in a ou.

For this i have this ps script:

```
Clear

############################################### Settings ####################################################################

$ldap_path = '...'  #secret

<# 1. '*' 
   2. 'XXX*'
   3. 'XXX-XXX*' (XXX sind Zahlen)

   Ansonsten den genauen String eingeben
#>

$search_filter = '...' #Filterparameter

##############################################################################################################################


#Alle AD-User mit Topdesk in Pager einlesen, Unterhalb OU Abteilungen

$Abteilungen = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $ldap_path -SearchScope Subtree -Filter 'Name -like $search_filter' | sort 


ForEach($Abteilung in $Abteilungen)  
    {    

       $Kostenstelle = $Abteilung.Name

       $Standort     = $Abteilung.City

       IF([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Standort)) {   $Standort = "Ohne".Trim() }  

       $DN           = $Abteilung.DistinguishedName


  Write-Host "Kostenstelle: " $Kostenstelle

  Write-Host "Standort....: " $Standort

  $searchb = "..."

$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter { pager -Like "topdesk"  -and Enabled -eq $true } -Searchbase "$searchb"

ForEach($User in $Users)  

       {
...# ???
}
...

    }
```

I want only read all UserObjects in the Department and change the attribute street to extensionAttribute2 and description to extensionAttribute1.

Comment: do you mean change attribute name, or set the street value to extensionAttribute2 ? (also side note: you better provide an English code, to make it easier for everyone)

Comment: sorry in my next question i change all to english

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this in a one liner.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Finance,OU=UserAccounts,DC=FABRIKAM,DC=COM" -properties StreetAddress,Description | foreach-object {Set-ADUser $_ -ExtensionAttribute2 ($_.StreetAddress) -ExtensionAttribute1 ($_.Description)}

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Finance,OU=UserAccounts,DC=FABRIKAM,DC=COM" -properties StreetAddress,Description | foreach-object {Set-ADUser $_ -add @{ "ExtensionAttribute2"="$_.StreetAddress","ExtensionAttribute1"="$_.Description"}}
```

**Second code example changed as per @kage comment.

Hope this helps.

Thanks, Tim.

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible, -ExtensionAttribute1 and 2 are not parameters for the Set-ADUser command, atleast its not on a 2012r2 DC maybe in 2016, but haven't tried that yet. Would need to set it using the -Add parameter as explained in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807496/adding-and-removing-extensionattribute-to-ad-object  Also the for-each is not needed, could just do the pipe and then the Set-ADUser it automaticly picks up the identity object then.

Comment: hey thank...do you know how  can check if the scriptPath attribute is  empty or not in a if else

Comment: Thanks @Kage, good pickup.
Without seeing what you are inputting, here is how I would do it.
if($_.scriptpath -ne $null)
    {
    write-host "ScriptPath has data"
    }
else
    {
    write-host "ScritpPath is empty"
    }

Hope the formatting works.